# How to measure similarity between sentences inside a cluster after clustering?

Tags: nlp, cluster-analysis, telegram

I'm conducting topic modeling analysis on messages from public Telegram groups, super new to this area so just learning.

I've been following this example here (https://towardsdatascience.com/topic-modeling-with-bert-779f7db187e6), and tried swapping out the HDBSCAN clustering algorithm with the one in BERT's documentation util.community_detection (https://www.sbert.net/docs/package_reference/util.html).

When I output the results of the clusters in this example (4899 Telegram messages), I get something that looks like this.

- Topic: just a cluster label
- Doc: all the messages in that cluster combined together
- 0: top keywords found via tf-idf

[image]

The problem I'm concerned with is that, there are clearly a ton of messages that are basically identical to each other, I've marked them in yellow. A few examples,

- Cluster 3: this is just a bunch of "hellos" and variations thereof
- Cluster 5: this is just a bunch of "Ok"s, people saying yes / ok
- Cluster 7: people just saying thanks and variations on that
- Cluster 9: some variations and misspellings of the word "gas"
- Cluster 19: just "siap" which I think means "sorry if I already posted"

To a human reader I feel like this type of text should just be excluded from the analysis altogether, the question is how do I detect it.

Since they're already grouped together by the clustering algorithm, the algorithm must have ways to measure the "similarity" between these messages within a cluster. But I don't seem to be able to find these values exposed anywhere or what it's called. Like for example the HDBSCAN algorithm (https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_hdbscan.html#), I skimmed through the doc a few times and didn't find any such property or measure exposed, am I missing something here?

My hypothesis is that for the cases where it's just a word or a short phrase repeated over and over again, this similarity value must be super super high, and I'd just say "clusters whose internal similarity is higher than this threshold are getting thrown out".

Any help & advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Index the corpus of your interest (for e.g. [FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss)) just for an idea, example code is below:

```
def build_index(self):

        """:returns an inverted index for the search documents"""
        vectors = [self.encode(document) for document in self.documents]
        index = faiss.IndexIDMap(faiss.IndexFlatIP(768))  # dimensionality of vector space
        # Add document vectors into index after transforming into numpy arrays. IDs should match len(documents)
        index.add_with_ids(np.array([vec.numpy() for vec in vectors]), np.array(range(0, len(self.documents))))
        return index
```

Then perform any similarity metric like L2 Euclidean distance or cosine similarity with dot products. Essentially, concept is that once we transform vectors in an n-dimensional space, vectors with similar semantics are grouped together. Therefore, computing similarity is just computing the angle between them and applying a cosine on it. Similar vectors have less angle, therefore higher cosine value & vice-versa.

Check the following topics for your problem.

- [Cosine Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)
- [FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss)
- [Sentence Vectors](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/08/top-4-sentence-embedding-techniques-using-python/) (similar to word vectors, but are good for long documents)

Check [this](https://github.com/VyasKS/personal_projects/blob/master/Natural%20Language%20Processing/Semantic%20Search%20Engine/long_document_search.py) repository for a better understanding of sentence vectorization and computing similarity to retrieve top n sentences.

In short,

1. Create an index file using FAISS for your data of interest.
2. Compute similarity by calling one of its methods.
3. Get top n most similar results.

Removing stop words:
Essentially your problem can be attributed to a list of finite stop words. If you can identify ones to some finite value (e.g. some 25) such different key words at max, then the task becomes stop word removal. Please use NLTK / Spacy libraries for easy stop word removal. You can also specify them in a list of strings, write a condition where if a token matches with one of those strings, they’re deleted from downstream processing. Stop words are omitted & is a necessary pre-processing task in NLP. Your task of telegram
data is also similar to Twitter analysis. Check [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/text-cleaning-methods-for-natural-language-processing-f2fc1796e8c7) & [this](https://analyticsindiamag.com/guide-to-cleantext-a-python-package-to-clean-raw-text-data/).

Comment: Hey @Sai_Vyas this isn't exactly what I wanted but this is good to know, thanks for telling me about the FAISS package! Seems quite interesting.